# cannot find module "child_process" in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am getting this type of error in runtime in ionic 2 project.

I want data from back4app serve.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the problem is that the module that you're trying to use might not be installed for you. From what I know, Back4App users can install their own modules by uploading a simple "package.json" file to their *cloud* folder. It needs to contain something similar to this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "module_name": "module_version"
  }
}
```

Also, if your module resides at Github then you'll just need to add a "git+" followed by the repository URL. The server will handle the installation and you'll be able to use the module properly.

If you have problems uploading the package.json you may always contact Back4App's Support Chat.